# Dynamic vs static/automatic memory allocation in C

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management

There are a bunch of post about this all ready on SO and I do understand that when using dynamic memory allocation pointers live beyond the functions they were created in. But I still seem to be a bit confused on the compile vs runtime part.

E.g. when the size of an array is first know at runtime it seems the rule is that you need to use dynamic memory allocation. But the below works just fine at runtime:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

  char * elems = argv[1];
  int intelems = atoi(elems);
  int array[intelems];


  for (int i=0; i<intelems; i++) {
     array[i] = 42 + i;
  }

  for (int i=0; i<intelems; i++) {
     printf("%d\n", array[i]);
  }

  return 0;

}
```

So *after* I have compiled the above program I can specify any size of the array I need when *running* the program.

What would have to be changed in the above example to make it more clear that it will not work unless I dynamically allocate memory for the array?

Comment: The above is not so much about dynamic memory, as it is about the storage duration of the array. Your array has variable length, but it still has automatic storage duration. If you were to use `malloc`, it would have *allocated* storage duration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> when the size of an array is first know at runtime it seems the rule is that you need to use dynamic memory allocation.

It *used to be* the rule, but modern C has [Variable Length Arrays](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Length.html). So the example above is valid.

You still need dynamic allocation if the size may be so large that it will cause a stack overflow.

You still need dynamic allocation if you want your array to exist beyond the scope of the function that creates it.

Comment: Ok so that boils it down to only use malloc when an array needs to outlive the function where its created or if its really huge.  This seems to be edge cases so would that mean its not that usual see malloc being used in modern C programs?

Comment: Those are not edge cases. Those are normal everyday cases, both of them. They may look like edge cases to a novice programmer.

Answer (score 1):

You use variable length (automatic) arrays, an addition of later versions of C (and as I have an older version of C, someone else may be able to explain it better).

Note that that the size of the array is declared (and known) before the declaration of the array:

```
char * elems = argv[1];
int intelems = atoi(elems);
int array[intelems];
```

The compiler now inserts assembler code to reserve space on the stack for the array, something like (pseudo assembler):

```
add sp, intelems*sizeof_int
```

Comment: [tag:c99]  is almost 20 years old. I swear people will be calling it "new" ten years from now, still

Comment: @StoryTeller, says something about my age...:-)

Comment: @StoryTeller Tell this to Microsoft.

Comment: @n.m. - Microsoft are on my personal wall of shame precisely for this reason. Thank heavens for `clang-cl`.

Comment: ...I'm just so used to finding everything around in VC, otherwise I would have changed long ago.